# Why is Jinja2 failing to convert python objects to string or int

Tags: python, html, templates, jinja2

Here is my original source code.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block css %}
        {{ super() }}
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/comic.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="comic">
        <div id="nav-container">
                {{ comic_path(int(panel_id) + 1) }}
                {{ str(int('3')) }}
                {{ int(panel_id) + 1 }}
                {{ int(panel_id) }}
                {{ isinstance(panel_id,basestring) }}
        </div>
        <img id="panel" src="{{ comic_path(panel_id) }}">
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Focus on the nav-container id. All of those python blocks were attempted but all of them fail with a `500 Internal Server Error` - an error in the application, and no errors are produced in the logs.

I don't have any further information that is relavent (the problem is truly isolated to those 5 example {{ }} blocks) , but I can answer any questions to help me figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jinja2 template code is **not Python code**, only Python-*like*. As such you are limited to functions listed in the [built-in filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) and [functions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-globals), plus whatever extra globals you explicitly added to template engine.

`str()` is not listed, nor is `isinstance()` and probably `comic_path()` is not either. `str()` is really not needed as that is what `{{ ... }}` interpolation *already does*, but there *is* a [`string()` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#string) that does the same.

Generally speaking, you pass *already processed data* to your template, including the result of the `comic_path()` call.

Sometimes it is advantageous to add a function as a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters) or as a [new global](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#the-global-namespace).  If you are using a ready-rolled integration of Jinja2 with a web framework, do look in the documentation for that framework to see if it offers an easy way to add filters or globals within its context.

If `compic_path()` is already a global, then `int` would be used like:

```
{{ comic_path(panel_id|int + 1) }}
```

as it is a filter, not a function.

Comment: comic_path is my custom global. So, are custom globals running Python code or Python-like code?

Comment: You need to then look at the *actual error message* (full traceback) you have, not just the 500 error message sent to the browser. Without a traceback there isn't anything more I can help you with here.

Comment: I'm adding custom global functions with this command
`app.jinja_env.globals.update(comic_path=comic_path)`

Comment: edit: no - the comic_path global works perfectly. You've already answered the question, I'm merely seeking more information. Thanks for the quick and good answer.